# How to run low voltage wire from one side of kitchen hood to the other?

Tags: drywall, conduit, low-voltage

I need to run low voltage wire for under cabinet lighting from one side of an exhaust hood to the other.  I would like to install a conduit so that the wire can be pulled later in the project (after backsplash is installed, etc.)  For example can we cut away the drywall, mount a 1/4" conduit to the 2x4s and burry it in compound?  If yes, what type of conduit should be used?  Is there something made for this purpose?

Also (and perhaps more importantly), what is the "right" way to do this?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the area?  Is there access from above (attic)? Does the hood exhaust to the outside?

Comment: 1/4" conduit won't be large enough. Most low-voltage wiring is similar to lamp cord. You'd only (maybe) get one pair through.

Comment: I'll try to post a photo later.  There is no access from the attic.  The hood is mounted on an exterior wall and exhausts outside. Actually the hood is not yet mounted. This is a typical configuration with 30" range hood between upper cabinets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this myself with both conventional range hoods and over-the-oven microwaves. Just drop the hood and cut one in. Avoid the areas where mounting screws will need to go, and avoid damaging your vapor barrier (if present). There's no need to patch the drywall.

Use any rigid or semi-rigid tubing that meets your size requirements. Obviously you'll want to position it so that it aligns with the holes you drill in your cabinetry.

UPDATE: 
From your comment I see that you'd like the wire to be under the upper cabinets. This is what I expected. My wire route usually goes through the side of the cabinet adjacent to the range hood, down through the cabinet floor at the rear corner, and wherever it needs to go underneath the cabinet, concealed by the recess. Sometimes it's necessary to clip a very small corner off the floating shelves, but it's not really visible from outside.

Of course, you can always run your conduit in the wall level with the cabinet recess since you're working on the wall anyway. The "right way" is what makes sense in your case. It's not a code issue.

Comment: Are you suggesting I install the tubing behind the range hood?  This would work but I would like to do it lower - just below the bottom of the upper cabinets.  The bottom of the hood is considerably higher than this and the wire would need to enter the cabinets rather than come out underneath.

Comment: Great. Thanks.  Now I just need to find something to use as a conduit.